# Modify the congestion control window value

Tags: linux, tcp, packet, cwnd, congestion-control

For my research, I would like to manually control the congestion control window size of TCP.

I want to explicitly stop the window from being reduced when segment/ack loss occurs on a test network.

Is this possible at all?

I have been looking into ways of doing this using Python, Netem and Scapy. I have access to both windows and linux (ubuntu 12).

Answer (score 3):

On kernels upward of 2.6.33 you can try

```
ip route change default via x.x.x.x initcwnd new-val initrwnd new-val
```

Also take a look at [this](http://fasterdata.es.net/host-tuning/linux/)

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. Add followings to the /etc/sysctl.conf file upon your requirment

```
#Maximum Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_max = 33554432

#Maximum Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_max = 33554432
```

Run "sysctl -p" to apply.